# How do I specify an AMQP correlationId with Kombu?

Tags: python, amqp, kombu

The [documentation](http://ask.github.io/kombu/reference/kombu.messaging.html#kombu.messaging.Producer.publish) suggests extra AMQP properties are passed as keyword arguments to `publish` as according to the AMQP spec, but `correlationId="foo"` does not seem to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you grep the source, you can see a bit where [Kombu itself fills out a correlation ID calling `publish`, in `kombu.common.send_reply`](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/00f7630a730c6b3757e777b9b6a676636dffea6f/kombu/common.py#L195):

```
producer.publish(
    msg, exchange=exchange,
    retry=retry, retry_policy=retry_policy,
    **dict({'routing_key': req.properties['reply_to'],
            'correlation_id': req.properties.get('correlation_id'),
            'serializer': serializers.type_to_name[req.content_type],
            'content_encoding': req.content_encoding}, **props)
)
```

`correlation_id` is the name of the kwarg used.